# Access scope created in ng-if

Tags: scope, dart, angular-dart

I want to access form's ngModels from controller. 
HTML looks like this:

`<div ng-if="ctrl.showForm">
        <form name="myForm">
            <input name="model">
        </form>
</div>`

Controller gets injected Scope object. After `showForm` is set to true I'm doing this: `scope.context['myForm']['model']`. However, `myForm` doesn't exists in context because `ng-if` creates its own scope.
Is there any way how to access the form from controller?